# VHDL function with no parameters?

Tags: function, parameters, compiler-errors, vhdl

Is it possible to define a VHDL function with no parameters?

I'm trying to compute the number of bits in a record type, but to do so it is necessary to create an instance of that type. Therefore, since I can't just define `const BITS = t_rec.a'length + t_rec.b'length`, I would like to define a function `function BITS() return natural` that instantiates a record `rec : t_rec` and returns `rec.a'length + rec.b'length`. However, the compiler fails with `unexpected '(')` at the function declaration, before it even reaches the definition.

I would just include an unused, dummy parameter, but I suspect that the lint tools would complain.

Defining subtypes for each record field in advance of the record would be too verbose.

Complete example:

```
package pack is function BITS() return natural; end package pack; package body pack is function BITS() return natural is begin return 0; end function; end package body pack;
```

Error message:

`pack.vhd:1:30: empty interface list not allowed`

Comment: The syntax for a function declaration is found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.2 Subprogram declarations, 4.2.1 General, where in the BNF you'll find the formal_parameter_list is optional (surrounded by square brackets, see 1.3.2 Syntactic description e)). An optional formal parameter list (4.2.2.1 Formal parameter lists) if present is an interface list (6.5.6 Interface lists, 6.5.6.1 General)  containing at least one interface element (see the BNF and again 1.3.2, a)). And that is what causes the 'compiler' error. Leave off the formal parameter list including parentheses.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] including the actual error message and I'd up vote your question. It does not appear to be a duplicate. I'd up vote an answer that explained why (VHDL syntax does not allow an empty interface list declaration).

Comment: @user1155120 So would I. Why does VHDL syntax does not allow an empty interface list declaration?

Comment: @user1155120 done, please upvote )

Comment: @MatthewTaylor done, please upvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should leave out the parentheses when defining a function with no inputs, eg:

```
function BITS return natural is
  variable rec : rec_t;
begin
  return rec.a'length + rec.b'length;
end function;
```

You should not include the parentheses when you call the function, either. eg:

```
report integer'image( BITS );
```

not

```
report integer'image( BITS() );
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5fMB

Comment: Can you please extend your answer and also add a calling example, because a function call has also no parenthesis :).

Comment: 9.3.4 Function calls, function_call ::= function_name [ ( actual_parameter_part ) ], actual_parameter_part ::= *parameter*_association_list, 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.1 General, association_list ::= association_element { , association_element }. At least one association and from 9.3.4 we see the parentheses and actual_parameter_part are optional (1.3.2 c)). 6.5.7.1 "If an interface element in an interface list includes a default expression ... then any corresponding association list need not include an association element for that interface element."

Comment: When using a procedure I was facing the similar issue mentioned above. Not including the parentheses fixed the issue for me as well. Thx.